# How to fill Scala Seq of Sets with unique values from Spark RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, set, seq

I'm working with Spark and Scala. I have an RDD of `Array[String]` that I'm going to iterate through. The RDD contains values for attributes like `(name, age, work, ...)`. I'm using a Sequence of mutable Sets of Strings (called `attributes`) to collect all unique values for each attribute.

Think of the RDD as something like this:

```
("name1","21","JobA")
("name2","21","JobB")
("name3","22","JobA")
```

In the end I want something like this:

```
attributes = (("name1","name2","name3"),("21","22"),("JobA","JobB"))
```

---

I have the following code:

```
val someLength = 10
val attributes = Seq.fill[mutable.Set[String]](someLength)(mutable.Set())
val splitLines = rdd.map(line => line.split("\t"))

lines.foreach(line => {
  for {(value, index) <- line.zipWithIndex} {
    attributes(index).add(value)
    // #1
  }
})

// #2
```

When I debug and stop at the line marked with **#1**, everything is fine, `attributes` is correctly filled with unique values.

But after the loop, at line **#2**, attributes is empty again. Looking into it shows, that attributes is a sequence of sets, that are all of size 0.

```
Seq()
Seq()
...
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Is there some kind of scoping going on, that I'm not aware of?

Comment: a question out of professional curiosity: If you are learning Spark now, why are you using the RDD API? Why not Datasets/Dataframes?

Comment: @maasg I'm not OP, but if I was just starting out with Spark, I'd probably start with the lower abstraction levels and work my way up to DataSets/Frames. Although technically this may not be "going up" the abstraction levels, there are still some things you won't be able to do unless you go raw RDD.

Comment: @maasg I agree with Yuval. I feel that compared to DataSets/ DataFrames, learning Spark with RDD's is both easier and more informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the fact that Spark is a distributed engine. I will give you a rough idea of the problem that you are facing. Here the elements in each `RDD` are bucketed into `Partitions` and each `Partition` potentially lives on a different node.

When you write `rdd1.foreach(f)` that `f` is wrapped inside a closure (Which gets copies of the corresponding objects). Now, this closure is serialized and then sent to each node where it is applied for each element in that `Partition`.

Here, your `f` will get a `copy` of `attributes` in its wrapped closure and hence when `f` is executed, it interacts with that copy of `attributes` and not with `attributes` that you want. This results in your `attributes` being left out without any changes.

I hope the problem is clear now.

```
val yourRdd = sc.parallelize(List(
    ("name1","21","JobA"),
    ("name2","21","JobB"),
    ("name3","22","JobA")
))

val yourNeededRdd = yourRdd
  .flatMap({ case (name, age, work) => List(("name", name), ("age", age), ("work", work)) })
  .groupBy({ case (attrName, attrVal) => attrName })
  .map({ case (attrName, group) => (attrName, group.toList.map(_._2).distinct })

// RDD(
//     ("name", List("name1", "name2", "name3")),
//     ("age", List("21", "22")),
//     ("work", List("JobA", "JobB"))
// )

// Or

val distinctNamesRdd = yourRdd.map(_._1).distinct
// RDD("name1", "name2", "name3")

val distinctAgesRdd = yourRdd.map(_._2).distinct
// RDD("21", "22")

val distinctWorksRdd = yourRdd.map(_._3).distinct
// RDD("JobA", "JobB")
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I'm still learning Spark, so this helped a lot. My problem is clear now, but I don't have a solution yet. I might try to achieve my desired results with Spark transformations/actions only.

Comment: Thanks for your solution approaches. This gets more complicated with a variable number of attributes, especially because I originally wanted to read the attribute names from file and not hardcode them.